# Increase by one per user per submit

Tags: django, django-models

I got the models shown down below.

I want that my invoice_id field gets the value 000001 when user A submits to it and as well 000001 when user B submits to it. It should auto increase from there, so if user A stays idle but user B makes other submits, B's next will get 000002, 000003 etc. If user C then joins and submit, he should get 000001 too. How would I approach this?

my models:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
  last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  # Company Profile Fields
  co_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="dashboard/logos", blank=True)
  co_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  co_address = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  co_zip = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  co_city = models.CharField(max_length=45)

  objects = MyAccountManager()

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

  def __str__(self):
    return self.email

  def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin

  def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True


class Invoice(models.Model):
  client = models.ForeignKey(BusinessContact, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user = models.ForeignKey(Account, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  invoice_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=6, null=True,
                                blank=True, editable=False)
  place = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date created', auto_now_add=True)
  date_sent = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date sent by mail', auto_now=True)
  date_deadline = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='payment deadline', auto_now=False)
  bank_number = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  iban_number = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  swift_bic = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  total = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  currency = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  paid_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  custom_comment = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  reverse_charge = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
      self.invoice_id += 1
    return super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user) if self.user else ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you declared your `invoice_id` as `CharField` but in your save method you are increasing it as `IntegerField`. So I think it should be

```
invoice_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
```

you don't need `unique` however you have to handle max value separately(check IntegerField documentation)

secondly, you don't need to override `save()` method, your `Invoice` model has a `ForeignKey` to your `Account` model, so for each user there will be one row in `Invoice` table just update the row on each submit, suppose

```
def submit(request):
    user = request.user
    try:
        invoice = Invoice.object.get(user=user)
        # already have am invoice. update it
        invoice.invoice_id += 1
        invoice.save()
    Except Invoice.DoesNotExist:
        # no invoice linked to user
        # create one
```